# if the Java code is strictly following concept in Java

Tags: java, dry, solid-principles

I am trying to implement the concept of SOLID and DRY here for validation. Dont know if it properly following these 2 principles.

// input (100:200:300) validation

```
private void test(final String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final String[] stringArray = input.split(":");
    if(stringArray.length != 3){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Parameter");
    }
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int thirdNumber;
    try{
        firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);
        firstNumber = firstNumber >= 0 && firstNumber <= 100 ? firstNumber : 101;
        secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]);
        secondNumber = secondNumber >= 0 && secondNumber <= 200 ? secondNumber : 201;
        thirdNumber = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[2]);
        thirdNumber = thirdNumber >= 0 && thirdNumber <= 300 ? thirdNumber : 301;
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(nfe);
    }
    if(firstNumber == 101 || secondNumber == 201 || thirdNumber == 301){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("false input");
    }else if (firstNumber == 100 && (secondNumber > 0 || thirdNumber > 0)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("false input");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking if we would review your code to see if you adhere to the principles of SOLID and DRY "the right way" or give tips how to better follow those principles.

That question might be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not following DRY or SOLID.

**DRY**

The first problem is that you repeat the parsing from strings to numbers for every number. I'm not a Java guy, but the first thing you can do is to create a new array of type int and loop through the string values.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    try
    {
        numberArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String '" + stringArray[i] + "' is not a valid number", nfe);
    }    
}
```

The second check seem to be based on their position in the array? Reuse that information in the loop above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    try
    {
        numberArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String '" + stringArray[i] + "' is not a valid number", nfe);
    }    

    var maxAllowedValue = (i + 1) * 100;
    if (numberArray[i] < 0 || numberArray[i] > maxAllowedValue) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number " + numberArray[i] + " must be between 0 and " + maxAllowedValue);
}
```

The third check cannot be changed but could be put at the bottom (without else).

That's for DRY.

**SOLID**

The problem now is that the method is not closed for modification. If your business rules change, you need to modify the method. Now you need to introduce a class and put that method in it.

```
public class NumberValidator {


}
```

The parsing is not a validation and it can therefore remain in the method, but the rest should be moved into a separate class (in C# I would use an interface):

```
public interface IValueValidator
{
    void Validate(int indexToValidate, int[] values);
}
```

.. and then just implement that one with two validations.

1. The one that checks the maximum value
2. One that ensures that value 2 & 3 are zero when 1 is 100.

By doing so you can introduce new rules without having to modify the existing code.

The final class would look like:

```
public class NumberValidator
{
    List<IValueValidator> _validators = new List<IValueValidator>();

    public NumberValidator(){
        _validators.Add(new MaxValueValidator());
        _validators.Add(new FirstValueValidator());
    }

    public void add(IValueValidator validator) {
       _validators.Add(validator);
    }

    public void Validate(string values) {
    {
        final String[] stringArray = input.split(":");
        if(stringArray.length != 3){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Parameter");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
            try
            {
                numberArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("String '" + stringArray[i] + "' is not a valid number", nfe);
            }    

            foreach (IValueValidator validator in validators) {
                validator.validate(i, numberArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course also move the `stringArray` initial length check to a validator.

***sorry for the c#/java mix, but I hope you understand what I'm going for.***

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Can you please let me know for the below code if it correctly following SOLID principle.

Comment: Please find the below link where I asked more on this matter, as I cant ask anythink here so created another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175117/if-all-these-3-classes-are-are-following-solid-concept

Answer (score 0):

[SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles are:

[Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - You are **not** adhering to this principle.

You are splitting the string, checking that there are three parts to it, parsing each part as an integer, checking each part is an integer and finally confirming that each integer is within a specified range. I count 5 separate actions that should be spread out into separate methods.

[Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) - You are **not** adhering to this principle.

To be *open for extension* you would need to at least allow for different limits for the numbers as they may well change over the life of the code. You are also not *closed for modification* as even the smallest change to requirements would require a change to this code.

[Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - Does not apply - you are not defining any object hierarchy.

[Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) - Does not apply - you are not defining any object hierarchy.

[Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) - Does not apply - you are not defining any modules.

The [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) requires you not to repeat yourself. You are **not** adhering to this principle as you repeat the same validation code for three different numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Can you please let me know for the below code if it correctly following SOLID principle.

Comment: Please find the below link where I asked more on this matter, as I cant ask anythink here so created another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175117/if-all-these-3-classes-are-are-following-solid-concept