# If all these 3 classes are following SOLID concept

Tags: java

I want to ask you something more on this matter for the below code for SOLID. If all these 3 classes are are following SOLID concept.

```
public interface A {
    public void calculate(String a);
}

public class B implements A {
    @Override
    public void calculate(String b) {
        System.out.println("value: " + b);
    }
}

public class C {

    private A a;

    public void show() {
        a = new B();
        a.calculate("test");
    }

}
```

Comment: They're principles, anyway. This questions pretty much has no meat on the bone and code can't get any more simple...

Comment: Class C may have some problem with these principles :)

Comment: Except for `Leskov Substitution Principle` all others are subjective any way. Since you do not have any subclasses, it doesn't matter. So, if you think they are SOLID, they are SOLID :)

Comment: Hello Reut,   Thanks for your comments. then how could be the code should look like for class 'C'. I didn't get any clue here.

Answer (score 4):

From how I look at things,

Class C breaks the

*Single Responsibility Principle* by handling two responsibilities, namely, instantiating other objects(instance of B) and the **show** functionality whatever that is. Object creation should be handled by a separate class and the dependencies should be injected to the users.

*Open Closed Principle* by being tightly coupled to B, whereas it could have depended on the interface A, thus being open for extension by using another implementation of A. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle#Polymorphic_open.2Fclosed_principle) for more information. In other words, C should have used A, and the actual implementation should have been injected to C.

Following is how you could write C to be SOLID.

```
class C {
    private A a;

    public C(A a) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void show() {
        a.calculate("test");
    }

}

class Creator {
    C createC() {
        A b = new B();
        return new C(b);
    }
}
```

`Creator` could be replaced by a dependency injection framework like Spring.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I hope the below code change will follow SOLID principle.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. then how could be the code should look like for class 'C'. I didn't get any clue there.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I am using simple java application no spring concept here. If I put a static method with the below code will it fine rather then creating constructor.                                                      public class Creator {

 public static A getA(){
  A a = new B();
  return a;
 }
 
}

public class C {

    private A a;

    public void show() {
        setB();
        a.calculate("test");
    }
}

private void setB(){
  a = Creator.getA();
}

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code snippet is following SOLID strongly.

```
public class Creator {

public static A getA(){
    A a = new B();
    return a;
}
}

public class C {

private A a;

public void show() {
    setB();
    a.calculate("test");
}

private void setB(){
        a = Creator.getA();
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, this class has the same issues as the first one. pubudu's solution is the correct one, you need to invert control to the Creator. i.e. rather than have C call Creator to get A, the Creator must pass A into C. C should not 'know' anything about Creator.